# Call multiple ClaimsEndpoint using Azure AD B2C custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using B2C custom policies, to get a third party token and then creating an Azure AD B2C token with that, which contains the claims of the third party. I am using **ClaimsEndpoint** in the **Technical Profile** in the policy.

The problem I am facing is, that I need multiple claims, and I can't obtain all of them using a single value of 'ClaimsEndpoint', and I need to specify multiple of those in my policy.

I couldn't find any relevant way to do so. Is there any way of doing that, using Azure AD B2C ?

Comment: Can't you just chain together multiple ClaimsEndpoint TechnicalProfiles?